# Redmine plugins folder location

Tags: directory, location, redmine, redmine-plugins

Soo my problem is that my brand new redmine install (2.4) has a plugins folder path like this:

```
/usr/share/redmine/lib/plugins
```

I would expect the plugins folder to be under `"something"/redmine/plugins`

Also, it's not empty which seems kinda weird for a clean fresh install.

I'm thinking that this directory is not the directory for the plugins install.

Anybody could give me a heads up whether I'm in at the right place or need to create the directory myself or what. :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I confirm you should create a new "plugins" directory in the redmine folder.
Then you just have to copy your plugins into this directory.

More help here: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Plugins

Answer (score 2):

locate redmine or find / -type d -name redmine first find where redmine folder is then create a folder called plugin and download the zip file or git clone.

restart the server sudo service nginx restart or touch /srv/redmine/tmp/restart.txt